# Где поставить запятую, если после вводного слова идет вводное предложение, а затем предложение продолжается?

Tags: пунктуация, вставка

Конечно - и я неоднократно говорил об этом, - мы будем уделять этому внимание.
Где в этом случае поставить запятую - после вводного слова или после вводного предложения?

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаемый вариант:

а) Конечно, - и я неоднократно говорил об этом - мы будем уделять этому внимание.

б) Конечно, - и я неоднократно говорил об этом, - мы будем уделять этому внимание.

Пояснение

1) "и я неоднократно говорил об этом"  - это вставка, которая всегда обособляется с помощью тире. Вопрос стоит только о постановке запятых.

2) Очевидно, что первую запятую надо ставить, так как вставка не относится к вводному слову. Вторая запятая может быть поставлена для симметрии, что допускается правилами.

Пример с одной запятой:

"Увидеть и услышать писателя для меня, провинциала, – я тогда работал в Сибири – было необычайным счастьем".

Примечание

В предложении имеет место повтор: об этом, этому, что является стилистической погрешностью.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, где можно прочитать об этом?

Comment: Например, в справочнике Розенталя  (вводные и вставные конструкции): http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

Answer (score 1):

Гхм. У меня одного впечатление, что это цитата Путина? Припоминая его обычные интонации (конструкция уж больно характерна), предложу следующий вариант:
Конечно (и я неоднократно говорил об этом), мы будем уделять этому внимание.

Comment: Вы очень наблюдательны. :-) Ваш вариант сомнений не вызывает, проблема в том, что вводное предложение мне обязательно нужно было обособить с помощью тире.

Answer (score 0):

В примере, которой вы приводите, преложение"И я неоднократно говорил об этом" не является вводным. Есть вводное слово "конечно" в составе сложного  предложения, после которого нужна запятая. Т.к. вторая часть сложного предложение имеет значение пояснения, необходимо двоеточие.

Корректно: Конечно, и я неоднократно говорил об этом: мы будем уделять этому внимание.

Comment: Вы это за автора решили, что не вводное? Он даже подчеркиевает, что вводное - с помощью тире.

Comment: behemothus, а что, автор сам решает,  какие предложения бывают вводными, а какие нет?

Comment: Я не вижу вводного предложения.

Comment: А кто еще? В рамках грамматики, конечно, но я не вижу здесь грамматических запретов.

Comment: Вы сами сказали:  в рамках грамматики.

Comment: А что видите? Либо вводное, либо однородное с "конечно" (даром что ли союз И стоит?). Ну как вариант: это запись устной речи, тогда всякая грамматика исключается.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24670/discussion-between--and-behemothus).

Comment: Я сказал, что грамматика вполне предполагает, что оно вводное.

Comment: ну я в чате. И что?

Comment: Я не могу писать в чате. Если администрация считает правильным удалить комментарии, пусть удалит.

Answer (score 0):

Хороший вопрос.

Я в подобных случаях не вижу причин переносить запятую после "конечно" в конец вводного. Смотрите, у вас тут тире заменяют обособление запятыми. И если запятую поставить после вводного, получится что вводное относится только к "конечно". Разве мысль автора в том, что он неоднократно говорил "конечно"? По первому впечатлению выходит, что он неоднократно говорил, что будет уделять внимание.

Но в вашей фразе конструкции очень странно выглядит союз "и". Может автор действительно ставит в один ряд (как однородные) "конечно" и вводную конструкцию, обособляемую с помощью тире. Тогда имеет смысл перенести тире в конец. Правда, тогда и способ обособления выглядит несколько странным. Боюсь, что тогда второе тире будет не нужно. Но это все гадание на кофейной гуще, лучше всего как-то переделать фразу, чтобы избежать двусмысленности...

Comment: Большое спасибо!